# YouTube V3 Search API PHP

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, file-get-contents

Im inquiring about an issues which i cannot resolve.

Our function is searching for YouTube Videos.
The function works however after fetching 10-20 links from the api( Youtube Links)
the quota over the google console api reach 10,000 and than we are unable to use the api anymore.
We can see over the the google console api graphs that the api reach 10'000, its restricted to our domain and valid (with Green V)

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Here is our PHP Function:

```
$searchUrl = $api_googlesearch_2_Ary['googleApiUrl'].'?part=snippet&q='.$artistName.'-'.$trackName.'&key='.$api_googlesearch_2_Ary['googleApiKey'];
    $response = file_get_contents(str_replace(" ","%20",$searchUrl), false, stream_context_create(array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false))));
    $data = json_decode($response,true);
    return $data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) says that the [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint has a quota cost of 100 units (so says that the endpoint's doc page). There's not much to do about it; except, maybe, to ask Google for a quota extension. You could also take into account minimizing the number of API calls: e.g. by caching the result sets obtained and query the endpoint only when strictly necessary.

Comment: Hi @stvar Thanks for your reply. How do i contact Google Api team? The only thing in their website is via stack overflow.

Comment: There's [this form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) that you'll have to fill in. Than wait for response -- which, according to the experience of users of this forum, doesn't arrive shortly.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance @stvar , i will follow this form.
If there is a change feel free to let me know.
Cheers